# VSIX project not loading zip template during build

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, vsix, visual-studio-templates, vsixmanifest

I am trying to create a VSIX which will have a multi-project template.

I've followed the instructions in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885241.aspx) msdn link and also included IWizard implementation for some manipulations.

I'm getting the below error while trying to build the solution:

> Could not determine the FullName of the Assembly at "C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MyTemplateSolution\MyProjectWizard1\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Cloud\TestTemplate.zip". Could not load file or assembly 'TestTemplate.zip' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.  MyProjectWizard1

The project structure looks like this : [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGhBy.png)

The vsixmanifest assets look like this :

`<Assets>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Assembly" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="%CurrentProject%" Path="|%CurrentProject%|" AssemblyName="|%CurrentProject%;AssemblyName|" />
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectTemplate" d:Source="File" Path="ProjectTemplates" d:TargetPath="ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Cloud\TestTemplate.zip" />
</Assets>`

template zip properties are below:
Build Action : Content
Copy To Output Directory : Copy Always
Include in VSIX : True

Comment: I think you have made a configuration mistake. Assemblies do not have `.zip` extensions, they are `.dll`.

Comment: @Crowcoder take a look at the msdn link mentioned above, the templates are supposed to be zip files.

Comment: I think the instructions are incomplete. I doubt the `d:Source` should be "Project" if  you are referring to a .zip file. This is how I assign the asset when my template is a Project, not an exported zip:     `<Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.ItemTemplate" 
           d:Source="Project" 
           d:ProjectName="BOSCCTemplate" 
           d:TargetPath="|BOSCCTemplate;TemplateProjectOutputGroup|" 
           Path="ItemTemplates" d:VsixSubPath="ItemTemplates" />
  </Assets>`

Comment: @Crowcoder When I include the c# item project in the same solution and add it as an asset to the VSIX project, I also get the same line as you. However, the .zip file generated by c# item project does not end up in item templates. Any idea why?

Comment: @Atizs I haven't done any vsix since I last commented but if I can refresh my memory I'll let you know.